# XSLT Tranformation of XML file containing CDATA

Tags: xslt, saxon, cdata

I have to transform an xml file using XSLT.

I had to get in the output the some structure of the input file file, expected some changes in some elements exsiting on a CDATA element.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:aa="http://example.com"
                  xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <aa:importOrder>
         <aa:orderNumber>00501010000342</aa:orderNumber>
         <aa:data>
            <![CDATA[
                <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                    <OrderImport xmlns="http://test.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
                        <OrderNumber>00501010000342</OrderNumber>
                        <Application>
                            <Student>
                                    <DataElement>
                                            <Name>age</Name>
                                            <Type>Int</Type>
                                            <Value>13</Value>
                                    </DataElement>
                                    <DataElement>
                                            <Name>firstName</Name>
                                            <Type>String</Type>
                                            <Value>taha</Value>
                                    </DataElement>
                            </Student>
                        </Application>
                    </OrderImport>
                ]]>
            </aa:data>
      </aa:importOrder>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

My expected output should be like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:aa="http://example.com"
                  xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <aa:importOrder>
         <aa:orderNumber>00501010000342</aa:orderNumber>
         <aa:data>
            <![CDATA[
                <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                    <OrderImport xmlns="http://test.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
                        <OrderNumber>00501010000342</OrderNumber>
                        <Application>
                            <Student>
                                    <DataElement>
                                            <Name>age</Name>
                                            <Type>Int</Type>
                                            **<Value>Other Value</Value>**
                                    </DataElement>
                                    <DataElement>
                                            <Name>firstName</Name>
                                            <Type>String</Type>
                                            **<Value>Other Value</Value>**
                                    </DataElement>
                            </Student>
                        </Application>
                    </OrderImport>
                ]]>
            </aa:data>
      </aa:importOrder>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

For that i used this xsl file:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="DataElement">
    <p>
        <xsl:apply-template select="name"/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Name | Type">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Value">
    Other Value
</xsl:template>
```

but I didn't had the expected output.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Which XSLT version, which XSLT processor do you use or can you use? The escaped XML inside the `aa:data` element requires a second parsing step that is only possible with XSLT 3 and `parse-xml` or with earlier versions and a processor dependent extension function.

Comment: I'm using XLST 3 with saxon-HE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To parse the inner XML in the CDATA you can use `parse-xml`, then push the nodes through templates that change the element value, then reserialize and make sure to define the `aa:data` as a CDATA section element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:aa="http://example.com"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" cdata-section-elements="aa:data"/>

  <xsl:template match="aa:data">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:variable name="transformed">
              <xsl:apply-templates select="parse-xml(replace(., '^\s+', ''))/node()"/>
          </xsl:variable>
          <xsl:value-of select="serialize($transformed, map { 'method' : 'xml', 'omit-xml-declaration' : false() })"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="Value" xpath-default-namespace="http://test.com">
      <xsl:copy>Other Value</xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank's for your reply, but i have a problem with: xsl:mode and map:  XTSE0010: Element xsl:mode must not appear directly within xsl:stylesheet   and    XPST0003 XPath syntax error at char 24 on line 17 near {...e($transformed, map { 'meth...}:
    map expressions require XPath 3.0/XQuery 3.0 to be enabled

Comment: I asked you about the XSLT version and processor, you stated 3.0 so I posted code that should work with Saxon HE 9.8 or newer.

Comment: the version that i'm using is Saxon HE 9.8.0-4, but i get this error. i don't if i must do something to enable the XPath 3.0/XQuery 3.0?

Comment: 9.8 was released as the first version to implement the final XSLT 3 spec, the error message to me suggests you are using an older version.

Comment: At https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nb9PtE5 you can see that the posted code works with Saxon 9.8 (it is 9.8.0.15 there but the XSLT 3 support  is the essential feature of the 9.8 release so 9.8.0.4 can't give the error you get).

Comment: i'm using saxon within a maven project and in the dependencies i have mentionned   <dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.saxon</groupId>
    <artifactId>Saxon-HE</artifactId>
    <version>9.8.0-4</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: I have added the tag for Saxon to your question, let's see whether someone from Saxonica like Michael Kay has a different interpretation of that error message; as I said, I only remember it from earlier Saxon versions before 9.8.

Comment: i forgot to mention that i'm using xslt under mule usb with version 3.9.0

Comment: I don't know about Mule and how to configure it to use the version of Saxon you have in your Maven dependencies, perhaps raise that as a different question with the relevant tags.

Comment: Well, you're definitely using a version of Saxon that doesn't support (or fully support) XSLT 3.0, and there's not really enough information here to tell why. You should really be on Saxon 10 by now.

Comment: I've just tried the 10.3 version of Saxon, but I've had the same problemes:  XPST0003 XPath syntax error at char 24 on line 15 near {...e($transformed, map { 'meth...}:
    map expressions require XPath 3.0/XQuery 3.0 to be enabled

Comment: @Youraf, rest assured that neither Saxon 9.8 nor Saxon 10.3 give you that error if you run them standalone, so it must be a configuration issue for your environment with Mule where I guess a default version of Saxon that is older is used even if your Maven dependencies name a recent version of Saxon. So as said earlier, better raise that as a separate question on how to configure Mule to use the latest Saxon version and XSLT 3.